# Recovering nonlinear functional effects (in a GAM framework) using spline design matrices

Tags: r, regression, estimation, generalized-additive-model, splines

I designed a simulation example to understand how splines can work in modeling non-linear functional effects of covariates in a regression framework. I generated the data from the following model:
$$
y_i = 2 + f(x_i) + \epsilon_i
$$
where $f(x)=2*
sin(x)$ and $\epsilon\sim N(0, 0.5^2)$. Then I used the B-spline design matrix to estimate $f$ (see the followin R code):

```
n = 100
x <- sort(runif(n, -3,3))

f <- function(x) 2*sin(x)
f <- f(x)
mu <- 2 + f
y <- rnorm(n, mu, sd = 0.5)

df <- data.frame(y, x)

fit <- lm(y ~ bs(x, df=5, intercept = FALSE), data = df)

est.fun <- as.vector(cbind(bs(x, df=5, intercept = FALSE))%*%coef(fit)[-1])
plot(x, f, type="l", ylim=c(-3,2))
lines(x, est.fun, col="red")
```

That is OK. However, I need to learn how to recover the estimated effects when I have more than one non-linear functional effect. For example suppose I have two functional effects as follows:
$$
y_i = 2 + f_1(x_{1i}) + f_2(x_{2i}) + \epsilon_i
$$
Please see the following R code:

```
n = 100
x1 <- sort(runif(n, -3,3))
x2 <- sort(rnorm(n, 0,1))
f1 <- function(x) 2*sin(x)
f2 <- function(x) x^2-2*x^3
f1 <- f1(x1)
f2 <- f2(x2)
mu <- 2 + f1 + f2
y <- rnorm(n, mu, sd = 0.5)

df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)

fit <- lm(y ~ bs(x1, df=5, intercept = FALSE) + bs(x2, df=5, intercept = FALSE), data = df)
```

Please guide me in estimating the effects using the related spline design matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use `predict()` to do the heavy lifting for us

The general idea is that you plot the weighted sum of the basis functions for each spline, with weights given by the corresponding coefficients for those basis functions.

Using your example:

```r
library("splines")
n <- 100
x1 <- sort(runif(n, -3,3))
x2 <- sort(rnorm(n, 0,1))
f1 <- function(x) 2*sin(x)
f2 <- function(x) x^2-2*x^3
f1 <- f1(x1)
f2 <- f2(x2)
mu <- 2 + f1 + f2
y <- rnorm(n, mu, sd = 0.5)

df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)

fit <- lm(y ~ bs(x1, df=5, intercept = FALSE) +
              bs(x2, df=5, intercept = FALSE),
          data = df)
```

the easiest way to do this is to use `predict()` with `type = "terms"`:

```
new_df <- data.frame(x1 = seq(min(x1), max(x1), length = 100),
                     x2 = seq(min(x2), max(x2), length = 100))
p1 <- predict(fit, newdata = new_df, type = "terms", se.fit = TRUE)
head(p1$fit)
```

```
> head(p1$fit)
  bs(x1, df = 5, intercept = FALSE) bs(x2, df = 5, intercept = FALSE)
1                        -0.7060489                          16.76951
2                        -0.8339985                          15.73805
3                        -0.9534053                          14.74576
4                        -1.0644132                          13.79198
5                        -1.1671660                          12.87607
6                        -1.2618077                          11.99736
```

Now we can plot, but it is simpler code if we massage the results into a nicer format first:

```r
p_eff <- cbind(new_df,
               bs1 = p1$fit[,1], bs1_se = p1$se.fit[,1],
               bs2 = p1$fit[,2], bs2_se = p1$se.fit[,2])
p_eff <- p_eff |>
  transform(bs1_lwr = bs1 - (1.96 * bs1_se),
            bs1_upr = bs1 + (1.96 * bs1_se),
            bs2_lwr = bs2 - (1.96 * bs2_se),
            bs2_upr = bs2 + (1.96 * bs2_se))

# and some limits for the y axis
bs1_ylim <- with(p_eff, range(bs1_lwr, bs1_upr))
bs2_ylim <- with(p_eff, range(bs2_lwr, bs2_upr))
```

and then plot

```r
layout(matrix(c(1,2), ncol = 2))
plot(bs1 ~ x1, data = p_eff, type = "n", ylim = bs1_ylim)
abline(h = 0, lty = "dotted")
matlines(x = p_eff$x1, y = p_eff[, c("bs1_lwr", "bs1_upr")],
         col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
lines(bs1 ~ x1, data = p_eff, ylim = bs1_ylim, col = "black", lwd = 1.5)
plot(bs2 ~ x2, data = p_eff, type = "n", ylim = bs2_ylim)
abline(h = 0, lty = "dotted")
matlines(x = p_eff$x2, y = p_eff[, c("bs2_lwr", "bs2_upr")],
         col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
lines(bs2 ~ x2, data = p_eff, ylim = bs2_ylim, col = "black", lwd = 1.5)
layout(1)
```

[image]

The above strategy works for univariate splines and if you fit a more complex model you need to have values for the other predictors too when you create `new_df`. As we're only plotting the partial effect for each term, it doesn't matter what you put in `new_df` for any non-spline terms, so long as they are consistent with the input data.

---

## Get your hands dirty & do it all by hand

If you want to do all the above by hand to see exactly what's going on under the hood, we need to delve into some matrix algebra

We have to create the basis outside of the model so that we can evaluate the basis functions at the values of `x1` and `x2` we stored in `new_df`

```r
bs1 <- bs(x1, df=5, intercept = FALSE)
bs2 <- bs(x2, df=5, intercept = FALSE)
```

Now we can "predict" from these objects to actually evaluate the basis functions for each spline at the points we want values of the spline for

```r
bf1 <- predict(bs1, new_df$x1)
bf2 <- predict(bs2, new_df$x2)
```

Next, we need the model coefficients for the basis functions of each spline

```r
betas <- coef(fit)
take_bs1 <- grepl("x1", names(coef(fit)))
take_bs2 <- grepl("x2", names(coef(fit)))
```

Here `betas` contains the coefficients and `take_bs1` etc are indicators of which values from `betas` applies to each spline. We also need the covariance matrix of the model coefficients

```r
V <- vcov(fit)
```

We can use the indicator vectors to select the relevant rows and columns from `V` to compute the standard errors of the fitted values.

OK; now we can get the fitted values for the new data. In math we have

$$\hat{f}_1 = X^{*} \boldsymbol{\beta}^{*}$$

where $X^{*}$ is the bit of the model matrix for the spline we are evaluating (note that this excludes the intercept), and $\boldsymbol{\beta}^{*}$ is the vector of coefficients for this spline.

In R we have do to some fiddling as the intercept in the model isn't the overall mean of $y$ yet the basis is centred about this. This means we need to recentre the basis functions about their respective means before we perform the above matrix multiplication

```r
mf <- model.frame(fit, new_df)
mm <- model.matrix(mf)
cm <- colMeans(mm)
bf1_X <- sweep(bf1, 2L, cm[take_bs1]) # subtract column means from basis
```

With that house keeping step done we can proceed with $\hat{f}_1 = X^{*} \boldsymbol{\beta}^{*}$:

```
peff_bs1 <- bf1_X %*% betas[take_bs1]
```

This gives us

```
> head(peff_bs1)
           [,1]
[1,] -0.7060489
[2,] -0.8339985
[3,] -0.9534053
[4,] -1.0644132
[5,] -1.1671660
[6,] -1.2618077
```

which matches that we got with `predict()` earlier:

```
> unname(head(p1$fit))[, 1, drop = FALSE]
           [,1]
[1,] -0.7060489
[2,] -0.8339985
[3,] -0.9534053
[4,] -1.0644132
[5,] -1.1671660
[6,] -1.2618077
```

For the second smooth we repeat a few steps

```r
bf2_X <- sweep(bf2, 2L, cm[take_bs2]) # subtract column means from basis
peff_bs2 <- bf2_X %*% betas[take_bs2]
```

which again, to check our working, matches with what we got from `predict()`

```
> head(peff_bs2)
         [,1]
[1,] 16.76951
[2,] 15.73805
[3,] 14.74576
[4,] 13.79198
[5,] 12.87607
[6,] 11.99736

> unname(head(p1$fit))[, 2, drop = FALSE]
         [,1]
[1,] 16.76951
[2,] 15.73805
[3,] 14.74576
[4,] 13.79198
[5,] 12.87607
[6,] 11.99736
```

Now we need standard errors, which are given by

$$\text{SE}(\hat{f}_j(x_{ji})) = \text{diag}\left (X^{*} V^{*} X^{*\mathsf{T}} \right )^{0.5}$$

where, again, the $*$ superscript is indicating we're only using the columns (and rows in the case of $V$) that relate to the current smooth of the various matrices.

In R, the above can be done efficiently (so we don't need to do all all those matrix multiplication steps) with

```r
se_bs1 <- drop(sqrt(rowSums((bf1_X %*% V[take_bs1, take_bs1]) * bf1_X)))
```

and checking our working we see the hand-computed values match the ones from `predict()`:

```
> head(se_bs1)
[1] 1.456848 1.409362 1.365446 1.324568 1.286244 1.250036

> head(unname(p1$se.fit[,1]))
[1] 1.456848 1.409362 1.365446 1.324568 1.286244 1.250036
```

The corresponding values for the second spline are

```r
se_bs2 <- drop(sqrt(rowSums((bf2_X %*% V[take_bs2, take_bs2]) * bf2_X)))
```

Note that all of this section has glossed over important issues such as pivoting that might have taken place inside `lm.fit`. If you need to know about that, then read the source code for `predict.lm` or run

```r
debugonce(predict)
p1 <- predict(fit, newdata = new_df, type = "terms", se.fit = TRUE)
```

and follow what steps it takes to figure out if you need to take account of pivoting (which reorders the columns of the model and hence also the order of the coefficients).

---

## Fitting your model as a GAM with automatic smoothness selection

As an aside, for practical usage, I find models that fit penalized regression splines more useful than the unpenalized regression splines used in your example, because penalized splines will do smoothness selection for you so you don't have to specify the complexity of each function (only some upper limit on that complexity [wiggliness]).

Here's how I would do this using a GAM fitted via {mgcv}

```r
library("mgcv")
library("gratia") # for plotting

# fit the model
m <- gam(y ~ s(x1, bs = "bs", k = 10) + s(x2, bs = "bs", k = 10),
         data = df, family = gaussian(), method = "REML")
```

Here I set the basis to use to the B spline basis (`bs = "bs"`) to match your example (the default in `s()` is to use a low-rank thin plate spline), and set `k = 10` as the upper limit on the effective degrees of freedom (EDF: wiggliness/complexity — in fact for identifiability reasons, only 9 basis functions will be used so the maximum EDF per smooth here will be 9).

```r
# plot
draw(m)
```

[image]

We can recover the EDF of the estimated functions:

```
> gratia::edf(m)
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  smooth   edf
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 s(x1)   4.24
2 s(x2)   7.36
```

and we see that while 5 df might have been OK for your first spline, that value was likely leading to some oversmoothing of the smooth effect of `x2` in the data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough response.